# Como acessar um indice de nomes em uma Series?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, índices

Estou fazendo uma função que informa se há uma coluna no dataframe que possui valores nulos. O metodo isnull() me retorna uma Serie onde o indice é o próprio nome da coluna. Eu não estou coseguindo exibir o nome da coluna, que é o próprio indice:

```
def possuiValoresNulos(df):
  serie = df.isnull().sum()
  for i in serie.index:
    if serie[i] > 0:
      print('A coluna ', serie[i].index(), ' possui', serie[i], 'valores nulos')
```

Quando chamo a função...

```
   possuiValoresNulos(base_poluente)
```

...tenho o seguinte erro: 'numpy.int64' object has no attribute 'index'

Geralmente temos o indice e queremos o valor, neste caso eu estou no próprio item da série mas não consigo exibir em qual indice eu estou, será que alguem sabe resolver isso?

Answer (score 0):

O que está acontecendo no teu código é que a variável *serie* é um inteiro Numpy, e esse tipo de dado não tem o atributo `index`.

Sugiro criar sua função desta maneira:

```
def possuiValoresNulos(df):
for coluna in df.columns:
    if df[coluna].isnull().values.any():
        quantidade = df[coluna].isnull().sum()
        print(f'A coluna {coluna} possui {quantidade} valores nulos')
```

A instrução `df[coluna].isnull().values.any()` verifica exatamente se existe algum valor nulo na coluna específica e, abaixo dela, tem a lógica que você já estava usando para contar os valores nulos em uma determinada coluna.

Comment: Olha que bacana... é uma busca por coluna e não por linha! Adorei :) muito obrigada.